# Greasemonkey script to pause video playback on non-active tabs

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey

Often when browsing in Firefox, I'll right click on a link, and open it in a separate tab to view later, and go on reading the current page. When the link is a Youtube script, however, playback starts immediately even though the tab isn't active. Other video players (like fora.tv and TED.com) don't start playback until you activate that tab.

Is there a [greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748) script that I can use to make sure that videos (and especially Youtube videos) are paused unless their tab is active?

Comment: Wait, are you looking to develop one yourself, or are you looking for a premade one?

Comment: Either one: if there's a premade one, then great; otherwise, if someone knows the relevant JavaScript to pause Youtube video when the tab isn't active, that would be great as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two options:

"Youtube Alternate Video Player" (greasemonkey script)
http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/13955

Script Summary:
Replaces the youtube flash video player with FlowPlayer flash video player.

- replaces the youtube player
- no hd
- no 16:9

Firefox Add-On "TubeStop"
http://www.chrisfinke.com/addons/tubestop/

- disables the autoplay on YouTube videos
- does it every time (even if the tab is active)

I will keep the TubeStop addon for now.

Comment: Excellent, just what I was looking for as well - even on tbe active tab.  Now I don't have to reload vids to save them with "Keep It!"

Answer (score 0):

I think Youtube now does this by default (only playing a video when the tab the video is in is activated)