# Pause/Play Youtube video from anywhere in firefox

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey

I often listen to music on Youtube, however it's hard to quickly find the YT tab, and hit the pause button. I was wondering if there was a plugin that would add pause/play buttons to my window chrome that finds the tab with the Youtube video in it and pauses or plays it.

Thank you!

Comment: This question is off topic as currently asked.  For help finding tools like this, ask on SuperUser.  But, I don't think one exists yet; a quick search of the usual channels didn't turn up anything. ... For making this yourself, Greasemonkey can't do it.  You'd need to make a Firefox add-on for this.  But this does not appear to be [a programming question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: apologies, I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847727/greasemonkey-script-to-pause-video-playback-on-non-active-tabs) asking a similar thing and thought it was a good place to add it. I will close the topic, thank you for looking into it for me though

Comment: Yeah, that question is off-topic for SO too.  The older questions for low-traffic tags didn't always get closed as well as they are today.